# .SVG Sunrise-Sunset graph: needs sets of 29 vertical gridlines for days of Months, 6 horizontal gridlines for 10m divisions of Hours

Tags: svg, edit, gridlines

.SVG Sunrise-Sunset graph: needs sets of 29 vertical gridlines for days of each Months, 6 horizontal gridlines for 10m divisions of each Hour!

The lines would need to be reasonably fine to maintain accuracy, but thick enough to remain visible.
If the new lines were only placed between existing lines, there would be 28 and 5 respectively between.

I would also like to lighten or change the blue line so the gridlines are more visible!

_

Although months have from 28 to 31 days in each, I suspect this would be far more complex.

I have never done anything like this before, so apologise that I am starting without any knowledge.
_

Original SVG 7zip https://easyupload.io/xsj8ze

gaisma-com-sunrise-sunset-graph.svg
[img][https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbAe1.jpg[/img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbAe1.jpg%5B/img%5D)

_

I am not allowed to add the jpg image for others to view, only link to image. If someone wishes to upload in a post so others can view I would be grateful.

Thanks,
Gary.

Comment: New users are not allowed to post images because StackOverflow is about you posting **your code** and us helping you fix **your own code**.  Break down your problem and show us your SVG code. Add a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click.